# Change xmlhttp.open value with option settings

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

Is it possible to change the value of xmlhttp.open with javascript ?

Im calling a xmlfile with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","prod.php?category=1"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

but I only get the first elements from my xml file since the category is 1
if I change it to 2, it prints out my second elements.

Can i change the category value with just a javascript from my dropdown menu ?

this is my form

```
<form>
Select a CD:
<select name="cds" onchange="showCD(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a CD:</option>
<option value="item1">item1</option>
<option value="item2">item2</option>
<option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Of course. Like you do with `+str`, you can use string concatenation to keep the category ID in a variable and change it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can surely do that by getting the value of dropdown.

```
// get the value from the dropdown
var dd_value = document.getElementById('dropdown_id');

// now you can append the same to the xml http request object
xmlhttp.open("GET","prod.php?category=" + dd_value + str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I understand, but still having the errors. but this is what Im kinda looking for, so all i need right now is some time :)
thanks